# Align material icon vertical IE/Edge

Tags: html, css, google-material-icons

I am trying to vertically align my icon in a button on IE / Edge.
It works in Chrome, FF ...

I have tried everything, without success.

This is a HTML code:

```
<button>
    <i class="material-icons valign add-property-button">
        add
    </i> 
</button>
```

I have created a Plunker (JSFiddle not working on IE) which demonstrates the problem: https://plnkr.co/edit/awk2usjeNjhi83DxLOr5?p=preview

Thank you in advance

Comment: I think you need use `button{ padding: 0; }` and `.material-icons{ float: left; padding: 4px; line-height: 24px; }` css for IE / Edge.

Comment: I tried that but it does not work either.